# AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding encryption in python

Tags: python, encryption, aes

I am trying to encrypt using algorithm AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING in python. I am getting correct data using online tool https://8gwifi.org/CipherFunctions.jsp but unable to implement it in a python. Please find below my code snippet.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64
import re

DEFAULT_KEY = 'dkdlko9876543210'


class AesCbc:

    def __init__(self, key=None):
        self.key = key or DEFAULT_KEY
        self.mode = AES.MODE_CBC
        self.size = AES.block_size
        self.pad = lambda s: s + (self.size - len(s) % self.size) * chr(self.size - len(s) % self.size)

    def encrypt(self, content):
        cryptor = AES.new(self.key, self.mode, self.key)
        encrypted = cryptor.encrypt(self.pad(content))
        return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(encrypted)

    def decrypt(self, content):
        cryptor = AES.new(self.key, self.mode, self.key)
        content += (len(content) % 4) * '='
        content = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(content)
        decrypted = cryptor.decrypt(content)
        try:
            return re.compile('[\\x00-\\x08\\x0b-\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\n\r\t]').sub('', decrypted.decode())
        except Exception:
            raise ValueError("inputted value can not be decrypted.")

test = AesCbc()

print(test.encrypt("value"))
```

But result differs. I want to achieve AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING encryption same as on https://8gwifi.org/CipherFunctions.jsp. Please help me in implementing the same algorithm in python script as well.

Comment: Well, yeah, linking to a website where some kind of numb-nut forgot about the IV is probably not going to help you. You could try an all zero IV of the same size as the block size. Currently you are reusing the key as IV, which is even worse as using no random IV at all.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I am a pentester. For my testing I need to encrypt using the same algo AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING and only that website is giving me the same data which matches one of sample. I need to reproduce a python script which generate same and its okay if IV is not used. Is there any way you can help me with to reproduce same output in python? I tried all possibilities but didn't worked.

Comment: I did just give you a hint, right? Sorry, I'm not going to test the zero IV myself.

Comment: There is a download link on that online page so you can get the code and see how the cipher is initialized. Use the linked docker container or the authors github project: https://github.com/anishnath/crypto-tool/blob/master/src/main/webapp/CipherFunctions.jsp

Comment: Seems the real encrypt/decrypt code is hidden here: https://github.com/anishnath/crypto-tool/blob/master/src/main/java/z/y/x/Security/CipherFunctionality.java and voila it is obvious what the IV is: `iv = new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`